# How to switch between 2 message bundles?

Tags: java, spring, internationalization

i'm having some issues handling the i18n of my webapp.
Is it possible through Spring to found a message in a MessageSource if it's not found in the other?

This is my Spring configuration

```
    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="xxMessage" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
    </bean>
```

Example: 
if the key is "login.user" and the locale is "en" the app shows the value in my xx_en.properties if exists, BUT i want to search in the other file (xx_es.properties) if the key doesn't exists.
Is that possible?

P.S: sorry for my english :D

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have interceptor configuration in your spring configuration

```
<interceptors>
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <beans:property name="paramName" value="locale" />
    </beans:bean>
</interceptors>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, for your answer @DDK i've already managed to resolve the problem :D

Solution below.

Define chained message sources, provided by the interface HierarchicalMessageSource.

For example, if you have your i18n files
   baseMessages.properties
and
   messages.properties

you could chain them as

```
<bean id="baseMessageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="baseMessages" />
</bean>
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="messages" />
    <property name="parentMessageSource" ref="baseMessageSource" />
</bean>
```